# Difference between service implementation and service deployment

Tags: theory, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am writing a distributed computing related paper. I have defined the specification of a service (abstraction) with its functional interface and guarantees. I have provided an algorithm which correctly implements the service and I have provided a proof of correctness for the algorithm. Now, I would like to discuss the real world implementation of the service and propose some optimizations for it. I wonder if I should refer to "the real-world implementation" rather as "the real-world deployment". I'm not sure if there is really a difference between usage of the words "implementation" and "deployment" in this context.

Comment: In some cases, deployment is used to indicate and 'instance' of an implementation and implementation indicates the 'template' of how your design manifests itself..

Answer (score 1):

**Service realization** (implementation of the service description) and **service deployment** are two phases of a service lifecycle.

**Realization** focuses on service technical implementation details. In this phase, implementation (coding) of the specification of a service is completed.

**Deployment** addresses the problem of installing, configuring and managing services and service instances in the service execution environment.

In the context of your question, I would refer to it as a possible optimization of service implementation during the realization phase. The algorithm (or the optimization) can be evaluated after the deployment phase (or after the service was deployed).